# How to use a timer in place of a while loop?

Tags: c#, timer

at the moment i am using a while (true) loop to do this. I am not very familiar with timers. can someone tell me how i would convert this to work with a timer?

```
string lyricspath = @"c:\lyrics.txt";
TextReader reader = new StreamReader(lyricspath);
int start = 0;
string[] read = File.ReadAllLines(lyricspath);
string join = String.Join(" ", read);
int number = join.Length;
while (true)
{
    Application.DoEvents();
    Thread.Sleep(200);
    start++;
    string str = join.Substring(start, 15);
    byte[] bytes = Encoding.BigEndianUnicode.GetBytes(str);
    label9.Text = str;
    if (start == number - 15)
    {
        start = 0;
    }
}
```

Comment: have you looked at how to use a timer.. Have you Goggled it.. there are thousands of examples out there...

Comment: He's right. Google really is your friend on simple stuff like this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why use a timer? I assume this is because you want to have the app remain responsive during such a supposedly long operation. If so cosider using the same sort of code but in a BackgroundWorker.

Also if you do specifically want to use a Timer, beware which one you use; the Systm.Timer invokes its event in a different thread to the one used by the applications hoting form.  The Timer in Forms events in the forms thread.  You may need to Invoke() the operations in a timer callback that change the label.

Answer (score 0):

This runs every 200 ms. But the suggestion to try Google before asking a question here is a good one.

```
using Timer = System.Windows.Forms.Timer;

private static readonly Timer MyTimer = new Timer();
...
MyTimer.Tick += MyTimerTask;
MyTimer.Interval = 200; // ms
MyTimer.Enabled = true;
...
private void MyTimerTask(Object o, EventArgs ea)
{
    ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Basically, a timer just sits there and counts, and every X milliseconds it "ticks"; it raises an event, which you can subscribe to with a method that does whatever you want done every X milliseconds.

First, all of the variables you will need inside the loop, that come from outside the loop, will need to have "instance scope"; they must be a part of the object that currently has this method, and not "local" variables like they are now.

Then, your current method will need to perform all of the steps prior to the while loop, setting whose "instance" variables I mentioned, and then create and start a Timer. There are several Timers in .NET; the two that would be most useful would likely be either the System.Windows.Forms.Timer or the System.Threading.Timer. This timer will need to be given a handle to the method it should call when it "ticks", and should be told how often to "tick".

Finally, all the code inside the while loop, EXCEPT the calls to Application.DoEvents() and Thread.Sleep(), should be placed in the method that the Timer will run when it "ticks".

Something like this ought to work:

```
private string[] join;
private int number;
private int start;
private Timer lyricsTimer;

private void StartShowingLyrics()
{
   string lyricspath = @"c:\lyrics.txt";
   TextReader reader = new StreamReader(lyricspath);
   start = 0;
   string[] read = File.ReadAllLines(lyricspath);
   join = String.Join(" ", read);
   number = join.Length;

   lyricsTimer = new System.Windows.Forms.Timer();
   lyricsTimer.Tick += ShowSingleLine;
   lyricsTimer.Interval = 300;
   lyricsTimer.Enabled = true;
}


private void ShowSingleLine(object sender, EventArgs args)
{
    start++;
    string str = join.Substring(start, 15);
    byte[] bytes = Encoding.BigEndianUnicode.GetBytes(str);
    label9.Text = str;
    if (start == number - 15)
    {
        start = 0;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Simply define a new timer:

```
        Timer timer1 = new Timer();
        timer1.Interval = 1; // Change it to any interval you need.
        timer1.Tick += new System.EventHandler(this.timer1_Tick);
        timer1.Start();
```

Then define a method that will be called in every timer tick (every [Interval] miliseconds):

```
    private void timer1_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Application.DoEvents();
        Thread.Sleep(200);
        start++;
        string str = join.Substring(start, 15);
        byte[] bytes = Encoding.BigEndianUnicode.GetBytes(str);
        label9.Text = str;
        if (start == number - 15)
        {
            start = 0;
        }
    }
```

***Remember to define the variables outside the method so you will be able to access them in the timer1_Tick method.**